# Webscraping with BeautifulSoup - NYC Marathon Times

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to programatically scrape all the NYC Marathon Data found here: http://web2.nyrrc.org/cgi-bin/htmlos.cgi/2112.6.038135231510781094 into a CSV.

**Two issues:**

1. I can't figure out a way to iterate over all the different years without manually supplying the URL that corresponds to a single year for all age groups 0-99.
2. Just focusing on a single URL (corresponding to one year of data), my code won't discover any tables.

   ```html
   def scrapeTime(url):
       f = urllib.urlopen(url)
       s = f.read()
       print " read: ", len(s), " bytes"
       f.close()

       soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
       print soup
    
       #iterate over all rows
       for row in table.findAll('tr'):
           col = row.findAll('td')
           FirstName=col[0].string # first column should have rank of runner
           LastName=col[1].string


   def main():
       url2013 = "http://web2.nyrrc.org/cgi-bin/htmlos.cgi/2112.12.076919132010781094"
       scrapeTime(url2013)
   ```

   If I just print the contents of "soup", the output looks like:

   ```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
       <html><head>
       <title>302 Found</title>
       </head><body>
       <h1>Found</h1>
       <p>The document has moved <a href="http://web2.nyrrc.org/cgi-bin/htmlos.cgi/33272.1.016990806717006432">here</a>.</p>
       </body></html>
   ```

   Except I can view the URL in my browser, just not through Python.  I suspect this has something to do with supplying headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something to fill out the search form for you and parse the results. You need more automation.

Here is a solution using [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library. I've added comments, but let me know if you have any questions about the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize

url = "http://web2.nyrrc.org/cgi-bin/start.cgi/mar-programs/archive/archive_search.html"

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.addheaders = [
    ('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3'),
    ('accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')
]
browser.set_handle_robots(False)

# get years
browser.open(url)
browser.form = list(browser.forms())[0]
select = browser.form.controls[3]
years = [item.name for item in select.get_items()]

# process year by year
for year in years:
    print "Processing year=" + year

    # open up search form again, fill out an appropriate year and submit
    browser.open(url)
    browser.form = list(browser.forms())[0]
    select = browser.form.controls[3]

    browser.form['input.searchyear'] = [year]
    browser.form['search.method'] = ['search.flat']
    browser.submit()

    # get overall winners
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.response())
    print soup.find(text='Overall Winners').parent.parent.parent.find_next_sibling('tr').find('pre').text
```

It prints:

```
Processing year=2013

  Men   GEOFFREY MUTAI, Kenya           2:08:24
Women   PRISCAH JEPTOO, Kenya           2:25:07

Processing year=2011

  Men   GEOFFREY MUTAI, Kenya           2:05:06
Women   FIREHIWOT DADO, Ethiopia        2:23:15

...
```

Basically, it opens up a search form, get all of the possible years from the `select` dropdown. Then, year by year, it submits the form and parses the results using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Sometimes I get the error, `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.` Any idea what would cause that?

Comment: @Parseltongue may be this is because of the hitting the site too often. Try adding a delay (`time.sleep()`) between the requests..